# Android Lint reports OldTargetApi when targetSdkVersion is 29

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-lint

I'm getting the following Lint error on Github Actions (current CI solution for the project)

```
 > Task :application:lint FAILED
Ran lint on variant debug: 1 issues found
Ran lint on variant release: 1 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///~/application/build/reports/lint/lint-results.html

64 actionable tasks: 55 executed, 9 from cache
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':application:lint'.
> Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.

android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
...
Errors found:
  
~/application/build.gradle.kts:17: Error: Not targeting the latest versions of Android; compatibility modes apply. Consider testing and updating this version. Consult the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES javadoc for details. [OldTargetApi]
          targetSdkVersion(29)
                           ~~
```

My `targetSdkVersion` is set to `29` already.

[image]

If I run the exact same command locally ( `./gradlew build`), no lint error is reported.

[image]

Some local environment data:

- Gradle wrapper 6.5
- Android Gradle Plugin 4.1.0-beta02
- Kotlin 1.3.72
- JDK 1.8.0_242

Any ideas on why this supposedly "contained" build is resulting in different outputs?

Comment: you can disable the lint?

Comment: Of course I can. But that doesn't solve the problem. I'm not willing to compromise quality and hence the question.

Comment: OK. I understand

Comment: It's happening again but with sdk 30 now...

Answer (score 4):

Not a proper solution, just a temporary workaround if you don't want to disable lint checks.

Create a `lint.xml` file in your `app` folder and list your build.gradle file to be ignored by lint:

```
<lint>
    <issue id="OldTargetApi">
        <ignore path="build.gradle"/>
    </issue>
</lint>
```

Comment: Don't you love Android? It happens with SDK 32 now :)

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you update your Android build tool chain to the latest version. Most likely your CI runner instances are set to always download the latest tools. Once the next version of the build tool chain is installed, it expects you to be targeting that version of the Android API.

So the solution would be to add an ignore for `OldTargetAPI` in your `lint.xml` like @dmytro-karataiev mentions or just don't update your build tool chain until you're ready to target the latest Android API.